Man who breathes out oxygen, short story
This could be by Asimov but I'm not sure, I read it in the UK in an anthology approx 1990.
There's a man who (for reasons I can't remember) is breathing the opposite way to everyone else.
He inhales CO2 and exhales oxygen.
The physician examining him is enraptured by this and keeps getting the guy to breathe in his face.
Further plot is possibly:- (but I'm not sure about this) that they want him on a spaceship to supply the breathing air

It should be noted that we all exhale a lot more oxygen than CO2 -- exhaled breath is about 16% oxygen and 4% CO2.

I remember a brief, humorous epistolary story from Asimov's Magazine, back in the late 1970s/early 80s, told in the form of a sci-fi "Dear Abbey" type of advice column, which included a segment about a woman seeking relationship advice concerning a reverse-anatomy alien man, who metabolized CO2 and expelled oxygen.

@MikeScott Yes, but that is a big alteration from the ~21% O2 and ~0.04% CO2 in the atmosphere.

I remember a short story. It was probably not yours. It is about a guy living on the Mars, trying to go home into his city. But his oxygen supply is depleted. In his last dying movements, he finally throws away the respiratory device. And he awakes, having a rare mutation, making him capable to breathe the Martian atmosphere. I can not remember its title, neither the author.

@Gray Sheep you were probably thinking of this one:- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/190229/short-story-about-a-young-man-stranded-alone-on-mars-who-runs-out-of-air?rq=1

@DannyMcG Yes it is!!! OMG! :-)

Ad Astra by Zenna Henderson. I read it in her anthology Believing.
The man who exhales oxygen is Marshall and the person who he breathes on is his friend Sanden. The story starts with them meeting in a crowded bar. Marshall has arranged the meeting there so he can breathe the carbon dioxide exhaled by all the people in the bar:
Sanden says of Marshall's breath:

Sanden’s head lifted. He sniffed and sniffed again. "Odd!" he exclaimed. "Like new-mown hay! How did a breath of wide, verdant fields find its way into this Black Hole of Calcutta?"

As you say, Sanden suggests Marshall should join space missions to provide oxygen for the crew:

"Look," said Sanden, releasing Marshall’s hands and tapping on the table with a bony forefinger, shifting slightly to the right after splashing in the sticky puddle again. "What’s one of the most pressing problems of space travel? Fuel? Certainly not after Mangowitznegellen’s astonishing discovery. Governmental approval? Not since we discovered that Senator—but no matter. What-is-this-pressing-problem?" His finger splashed five times in the sticky puddle. "The breath of life! Just that. The breath of life. But you!" Marshall blinked at the reverence of Sanden’s eyebrows. "You not only exhale oxygen, but you utilize that problem byproduct of normal breathing, CO₂!"

